# Tensor types within tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have been struggling to create a simple classifier in tensorflow using the estimator classes. (learning tensorflow to take advantage of some advanced features, rather than using Keras, which indeed makes this problem simple, learning is hard sometimes.  I digress).

I took the original tutorial for MNIST data located here:
https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/notebooks/3_NeuralNetworks/neural_network.ipynb

I wrote a new input function for my own data (

Xtrain.shape=(595212, 57)

target.shape=(595212,):

```
import pandas as pd
train=pd.read_csv("../input/train.csv")
test=pd.read_csv("../input/train.csv")
target=train['target']
Xtrain=train.drop(['id','target'],axis=1)
# Define the input function for training
input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={'data': Xtrain.as_matrix()}, y=target,
    batch_size=batch_size, num_epochs=1, shuffle=True)
```

I finally got a binary classifer for my own data working.  But I had to modify the neural net (I did it by trial and error, without much understanding and tyring to decipher error codes).

I had to do a reshape of the output of the next and a cast of the labels.  But I don't know WHY i needed to do it.  I struggled mightly over the evening with tensor dimensions and am really quite at a loss (no  pun intended) as to why these modifications are needed.  I am thinking it has do do with the underlying data flow, but I just can't seem to get my head around what went wrong or why this was needed.

The original code is commented out in the section delineated by the '####' 
Obviously for binary classification, I removed the softmax and switched to the current loss.

My model is defined as :

```
# Define the model function (following TF Estimator Template)
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):

    # Build the neural network
    logits = neural_net(features)

    # Predictions
    pred_classes = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1)
    pred_probas = tf.nn.sigmoid(logits)

    # If prediction mode, early return
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=pred_probas) 

    # Define loss and optimizer
    #############################################################
    #loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
    #    logits=logits, labels=tf.cast(labels, dtype=tf.int32)))
    loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        logits=tf.reshape(logits,[-1]), labels=tf.cast(labels, dtype=tf.float64)))
    ###########################################################
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate)
    train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_op, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())

    # TF Estimators requires to return a EstimatorSpec, that specify
    # the different ops for training, evaluating, ...
    estim_specs = tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
      mode=mode,
      predictions=pred_probas,
      loss=loss_op,
      train_op=train_op)


    return estim_specs
```